# Stopping a looping AudioClip in Java program

Tags: java, audio

I have an assignment where I am building a game and need background music looping.  I am using `java.Applet.AudioClip` which according to Oracle has three built in functions.  `play()`, `loop()`, and `stop()`.  For some reason my stop only works sometimes.  There is a menu item called sound which turns the sound off and on for the game, there is also a pause button.  The pause button successfully stops the music, and playing starts it again.  But if I uncheck the sound option, all the sounds stop except for the background music (I've debugged and it's going into the if statement to stop the background music but for some reason it doesn't stop it).  If I pause the game, uncheck the sound option, then unpause the game the background music stays off.  Unchecking the sound (and the sound not stopping), pausing the game, and then unpausing starts the music (even though it shouldn't).  So basically unchecking the sound option works for all sounds except for background music, and it works for background music but only if turned off while paused.  Thank you for your time and I hope to hear back from you shortly.

(Since this is for a class assignment I don't want to get in trouble for sharing my code so other classmates can find it so I will try to not share my entire class and only post the relevant snips and if you need more just let me know)

```
`ItemListener listener = new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            int state = event.getStateChange();
            if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                gw.setSound(true);
                if (!gameMode) {
                    backgroundSound.loop(gw);
                }
                gw.notifyObserver();
            }
            else
            {
                gw.setSound(false);
                backgroundSound.stop(gw);
                gw.notifyObserver();
            }
        }
    };`

`if (e.getSource() == pauseBtn) {
        if (pauseBtn.getText().equals("Pause")) {
            timer.stop();
            backgroundSound.stop(gw);
            pauseBtn.setText("Play");
} else if (pauseBtn.getText().equals("Play")) {
            timer.start();
            if (gw.getSound())
            {
                backgroundSound.loop(gw);
            }
            pauseBtn.setText("Pause");
}`
```

Comment: The concept of background music should be elaborated.

Comment: A looping audio clip that plays in the background (meaning there are foreground sounds) the entire length of the game.  Only silenced by pausing or muting the game.